# How to read a property in the an XML properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created an XML properties file which contains an sql query as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="sample.select">
        <![CDATA[
            The SQL query goes here
        ]]>
    </entry>    
</properties>
```

In my DAO I want to get the property "sample.select", but I don't know how is that done in Spring Boot, when I googled about it I found that I have to add the annotation `@ImportResource("classpath:my-file.xml")` to the Application class, but I want to read the ressource file inside my DAO class and not the Application class.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `@Bean` in your Configuration class with the informations that you read in the Configuration. After that, you can inject the Bean in the DAO class.

Example:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:my-file.xml")
@Configuration
public class SampleSelectConfig {

    private @Value("#{sample.select}") String select;

    @Bean
    String mySqlFromXml() {
        return select;
    }
}
```

And in your DAO you can inject the Bean:

```
@Component
class YourDAO {

    @Autowired
    private String mySqlFromXml;

}
```

I couldn't test the code above, but the idea is the same.

Comment: So do I have to create a new configuration file or work with the Application class ?

Comment: Create a new Configuration class. You don't need to do that on the Application class

Comment: Okey, thank you, what about using a `.properties` file instead of the xml file, for that I won't need to create a configuration file, I'll just use the `@PropertySource` annotation on the DAO class and then `@Value("${sample.select}")  private String mySqlFromXml;`

Comment: To use PropertySource, [you need](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) to use it in a Configuration class.