# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: java, xml

I want to use an XML file that has settings params in it and automatically associate it with the class component fields so that it is reusable as a configuration class in the future. I was basing on post: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903276/how-to-read-a-property-in-the-an-xml-properties-file-in-spring-boot).

My file configuration.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <server serverport="1111"/>
  <client clientport="1111">
    <ServerHost>localhost</ServerHost>
  </client>
</config>
```

My classes are as follows:

```
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:configuration.xml")
@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Config {
  private Server server;
  private Client client;
}
```

Client.java

```
@Getter
public class Client {
  private @Value("#{clientport}") String clientPort;
  private String serverHost;
}
```

Server.java

```
@Getter
public class Server {
  private @Value("#{serverport}") String serverPort;
}
```

pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.Java</groupId>
  <artifactId>advanced</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

With this approach I am receiving an error like:

```
Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [configuration.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 9; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'config'.
```

and

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'config'.
```

I am a little bit confused because seemingly it looks fine but I cannot find a source of this error. I will be grateful for a suggestion of how to solve this problem in my application and make it reusable as a class with configuration parameters from XML file.

EDIT:
If you know another approach to reach a desirable goal feel free to post it.

EDIT2:
I found walkaround for this problem but I hope that there will another solution which will bring a desirable effect: [click](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/convert-xml-to-properties/)